# Fragmentation element overlap issue?

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus

I design an activity which is using full screen fragment(A), it have some button on screen (like https://i.stack.imgur.com/siQHT.png).

Now from this fragment(A) launching another full screen fragment(B). Now problem here, I still can access element of Fragment(A), Focus is shifting in both fragment.

Does any one have idea how to restrict access of parent fragmnet(i.e. fragment A) when launching other fragment over that?

**EDIT:**

Here is code to add fragment :

```
private void addFragmentToStack(Fragment fragment) {
            logv(TAG, "addFragmentToStack", "");
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.llMain, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

where llMain belongs Activity layout.

Comment: Can you post the code that displays fragment B?

Comment: @ Brett Duncavage please find edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the fragment instead of adding the new one.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("someuniquestring");
ft.replace(R.id.llMain, fragment); // can add 3rd parameter for tag if you want to get this fragment later
ft.commit();
```

That will replace the old fragment with the new one and add the previous transaction to the back stack so when "back" is pressed the previous fragment will be restored.

Comment: here what need to do come back from fragment B to fragment A, in this case will fragment A will maintain it's last state?

Comment: If you override `onSaveInstanceSate` in fragment A's implementation you can save data in the `Bundle` which will be given to the next call of `onCreate`, so you can then repopulate the UI.

Comment: That I did but I am getting bundle object NULL.